# openapi-generator can't handle status code 204

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

Using the npm package  `"@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.4.25",` I get an `Json-Parse`-Error when my api returns status code 204 (without body).

Having a look into the generated code the `return new runtime.JSONApiResponse(response, (jsonValue) => TaskFromJSON(jsonValue));` is always called for all responded status codes.

How can I fix this without changing the generated code?

```js
async getTasksRaw(requestParameters: GetTaskByIdRequest, initOverrides?: RequestInit): Promise<runtime.ApiResponse<Task>> {
        if (requestParameters.taskId === null || requestParameters.taskId === undefined) {
            throw new runtime.RequiredError('taskId','Required parameter requestParameters.taskId was null or undefined when calling getTaskById.');
        }

        const queryParameters: any = {};

        const headerParameters: runtime.HTTPHeaders = {};

        const response = await this.request({
            path: `/tasks/{taskId}`.replace(`{${"taskId"}}`, encodeURIComponent(String(requestParameters.taskId))),
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headerParameters,
            query: queryParameters,
        }, initOverrides);

        return new runtime.JSONApiResponse(response, (jsonValue) => TaskFromJSON(jsonValue));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/7720 (the title says "TypeScript" but the commmens confirm that other generators have the same issue)

Comment: Any idea how to fix this respectivly how to create a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, currently I fixed it by the following middleware:

```js
import { HttpExceptionFromJSON, Middleware, ResponseContext } from './my-client';

/**
* Workaround
*/
export default class NoContentMiddleware implements Middleware {
    public post?(context: ResponseContext): Promise<Response | void> {
        if (context.response.status === 204) {
            throw {
                status: 204
            };
        }
        return Promise.resolve(context.response);
    }
}
```

Then I inject the middleware to the client:

```js
const config = new Configuration({
    basePath: apiGateway + '/api/myapi',
    middleware: [new NoContentMiddleware()]
});
```

using the client:

```js
public async test(){
    try{
       var myentity = await this.callAPI();
    catch(e:any){
        switch(e.status){
            case 204:
                console.log("no content");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("unexpected error");
        }
    }
}
```